# Installing Five9 managed package in scratch org doesn't install all fields on Activity

Tags: sandbox, scratch-org

We're spinning up a scratch org and trying to install [the Five9 Managed Package](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001gGgIEAU) in the org with the following command:

```
sfdx force:package:install --package 04t2K000000Fz05QAC --securitytype=AllUsers --targetusername Scratch --wait 60
```

The install succeeds:

> Successfully installed package [04t2K000000Fz05QAC]

However, it's not installing all the custom fields on the Activity object it's supposed to.

In our **sandbox** installs, we see fields like `Five9__Five9ANI__c`. I see these in the sandbox > managed package > components page, like "Five9 ANI" on Activity.

However in the **scratch org** install, we're only seeing two Five9 custom fields on activity (there should be many, including `Five9__Five9ANI__c`):

[image: five9 custom fields on activity]

And our components fail to deploy with errors like

> Class MyClass : Field does not exist: Five9__Five9ANI__c on Task

What could cause a package to install different custom fields based on if it's a scratch org or a sandbox?

Comment: Check the package versions ? Are you sure both of them are same package versions ?

Comment: How can I get older package version install IDs from the App Exchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea if this will be relevant to anyone else, but we found installing an older package of Five9 made the fields visible in a scratch org:

The current latest package ID, `04t2K000000Fz05QAC`, does not appear to install all expected custom fields on a task. Its version number is `2.46`.

An older Five9 managed package version, with version ID `04t2K000000KSrfQAG`, and version number `2.41.0.14` does contain the expected fields.

We haven't seen high software quality from Five9, which might explain why a minor package version bump introduces such unexpected changes. But we don't have any insight into the issue because we can't view the install process for managed packages.

**Edit: From Five9 Support:**

> the missing log mapping is a known issue if you installed directly version 2.46. For reference, please see Article Number 000019209 (Salesforce | How to create Five9 related Activity Custom Fields).

https://community.five9.com/s/article/Salesforce-How-to-create-Five9-related-Activity-Custom-Fields (have to be logged in to see)

So this is an issue with Five9 publishing buggy / breaking changes

Answer (score 1):

This actually appears to be intentional behavior and I suspect is due to the field limit on Activity. The Five9 documentation states that in newer versions of their managed package only *2* mandatory fields are added automatically, and that others must be created manually. This gives you the flexibility to decide which of the fields you need and which you do not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).